# Extjs Combo - type text header and it will be focus to select

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have 'xtype: combe' like **http://jsfiddle.net/KYRhC/**

```
{
        xtype        : 'combo',
        fieldLabel   : 'Letter',
        store        : mySimpleStore,
        displayField : 'name',
        typeAhead    : true,
        autoSelect: true,
        triggerAction:  'all',
        forceSelection: true,

        editable:       false,
        mode         : 'local'
    }
```

I want when i click to selectbox and type header of text and it will be focus to select 
example type d -> D will focus to select

 I have option **typeAhead    : true,** but not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set

1. `editable: true`
2. `minChars: 1`

see **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/sran/KYRhC/1/)**

Note that the search will ignore case so `d` and `D` is the same

As commented by @rixo

> instead of mode which is deprecated, use queryMode to have the combo
>   react really quickly.

Comment: Also, instead of `mode` which is deprecated, use `queryMode` to have the combo react really quickly.

Comment: I don't want allow user type. I have used  editable: false?. Any idea for that

Comment: @freestyle You didn't made that clear in your question. Well out of the box typeAhead requires the user to made a input in the combo which is ok because user want to see what he had entered with the possibility to remove it again or correct it. In your case you will have to catch keystrokes each time the picker is visible and apply the manually. And that is just a easy description of what to do. I think this gets ugly... I would drop that approach and let the user enter a value to filter.